# Push notifications sound not coming

Tags: python, react-native, push-notification, pyfcm

I tried to use like below

I am using pyfcm to send notifications (https://github.com/olucurious/PyFCM/).

```
push_service = FCMNotification(api_key)
push_service.notify_multiple_device(registration_ids=registration_ids, message_title=message_title,
message_body=message_body, data_message=data_message, sound="Default")
```

I added sound="Default" as last parameter of that function. But mobile not making any sounds even though notification is coming.

This is a react native application but I think react native has nothing to do here because any mobile app doesnt even know when the notification comes in background.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Is it a real cell phone? Are both Android and iOS the same?

Comment: I tested only in Android redmi note 7

Comment: what are you using to receive notifications on React-native

Comment: I am not doing anything. Even if we dont write any code, notification comes(but no sound in my case). But when we click that notification, then our code will run. So I think its not about react native. Something else, may be pyfcm has some issue?

Answer (score 0):

you should put sound=True

```
push_service.notify_topic_subscribers(
    message_body=message, topic_name=topic_condition, sound=True)
```